# How to include/require file from a folder above the root in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have installed php like this:

```
version: '3.3'
     services:
       web:
         image: php:7.3-apache
         container_name: php73
     volumes:
       - ./php:/var/www/html/
     ports:
       - 8000:80
```

and it works.

But I want to include some file from a folder outside html folder and it fails.

My code for include inside of index.php in the root folder is `require __DIR__ . '/../nonpublicfolder/includeme.php';` but it fails. With error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/../nonpublicfolder/includeme.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4
```

So, I was thinking I have to somehow set up the document root to /var/www/html/ as it is now, but change the include_path to just /usr/local/lib/ instead of /usr/local/lib/php ?

How to do that, so I can include stuff from outside the html public directory and simulate the real live webserver environment where the nonpublic folder is outside of html (public_html) folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not related to the include path. `__DIR__ . '/../nonpublicfolder/includeme.php'` is a complete path, "relative" to the script directory. You need to mount also `./nonpublicfolder`

Something like this should work:

```
version: '3.3'
     services:
       web:
         image: php:7.3-apache
         container_name: php73
     volumes:
       - ./php:/var/www/html/
       - ./nonpublicfolder:/var/www//nonpublicfolder/
     ports:
       - 8000:80
```

Comment: Thanks, the missing mounting of the folder was the case. Now it works.